# TextInputLayout hint color not changing on setting error using support version 28.0.0-alpha3

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am working on Login page which contains TextInputLayout. During validation on showing error error is showing with red color but "hint" is also showing with red color. Why this is happening? I am using API level 28 but on changing API level to 27 and using below code hint color get changed with textGrey on on showing error. Is this is a problem with API levels?

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/createAccountFullNameTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textGrey">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/createAccountFullNameNameEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Full Name"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/textGrey" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Any update regarding this issuee?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
app:hintTextAppearance="@style/EditTextHintStyle"
```

Here is the correct style

```
<style name="EditTextHintStyle" parent="EditTextBaseStyle">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/color_grey</item>
```

Comment: I have already tried this style:                <style name="MyAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Blue</item>
    </style>